# Установка значений сессии с использованием метода

Tags: php, сессия, global-variables

Прошу подсказать по заданию из учебника:

> Необходимо создать класс-обертку для сессии, метод set() которого
>   позволяет устанавливать значение сессии, get() считывать ранее
>   установленное значение.

Т.к. я не совсем понял что имеют в виду под установлением значением сессии (просто добавить значение в массив $_SESSION или добавить ключ+значение), то я выбрал второй вариант.

Главная проблема в том, что если ранее в $_SESSION, например, вносили 1 - 2 (1 - ключ, 2 - значение) и потом решили внести 2 - 1 (2 ключ - 1 значение), то в массив $_SESSION не добавляется новый элемент, а меняется существующий (1 - 2 => 2 - 1).
Если добавлять новые пары ключ+значение со значениями отличными от содержащихся в массиве $_SESSION, то добавление происходит без проблем.
Почему так происходит?

Очистка сессии идет если проставлен крыж на чекбоксе и нажата кнопка "Очистить".

```
<?php
print_r($_SESSION);
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}

$check_value = isset($_POST['sesunset']) ? 1 : 0;
if ($check_value) {
    session_unset();
    session_start();
    $check_value = 0;
}


if (isset($_POST['setval']) && isset($_POST['setvar'])) {
    Session::set($_POST['setvar'],$_POST['setval']);
}

class Session
{
    public static function set($var, $val)
    {
        $_SESSION[$var] = $val;
    }

}

print_r($_SESSION);


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method="post">
            <p>Переменная</p><input type="text" name="setvar" value="">
            <p>Значение переменной сессии</p><input type="text" name="setval" value="">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Добавить">
        </form>

        <form method="post">
            <span>Обнулить $_SESSION?</span><input type="checkbox" name="sesunset">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Обнулить">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это нормальное поведение сессии
У вас каждый раз будет перезаписываться значение ключа

```
$_SESSION[$var]
```

Используйте ваш ключ как массив и добавляйте ему значения.
Например $_SESSION['customer_session'][] = ['foo', 'bar];